# Jquery hide and show table rows in laravel dynamic table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I've been trying to get showing and hiding certain table rows to work in a dynamically generated table. The table itself gets its data from a laravel collection.
The idea behind the table is that we want to have users to show labelgroups, these groups can have zero, one, or more labels with that group number. I display the labels under their appropriate group.

The code is as follows:

```
<table id="labeltable" class="table table-bordered">
  @foreach($labelgroups as $labelgroup)
    @foreach($labelgroup->all() as $groep)
      <!-- Als de laatst ingevulde groep door de foreach loop verschillend is van de huidige groep, vul die dan in.
           Anders vul je deze en de rest van de headers niet in en wacht je tot er een nieuwe header is. -->
      @if($lastgroup !== $groep->groep)
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td></td><!-- Empty line -->
          </tr>
          <tr style="background-color: #5cb85c">
            <th>{{ $groep->groep }}</th>
            <!-- Laatst ingevulde groep bepalen -->
            {{ $lastgroup = $groep->groep }}
            @if($event->present()->nl)
              <th>{{Initialise::lang('lbl.algemeen.taal_1')}}</th>
            @endif
            @if($event->present()->fr)
              <th>{{Initialise::lang('lbl.algemeen.taal_2')}}</th>
            @endif
            @if($event->present()->en)
              <th>{{Initialise::lang('lbl.algemeen.taal_3')}}</th>
            @endif
            @if($event->present()->de)
              <th>{{Initialise::lang('lbl.algemeen.taal_4')}}</th>
            @endif
          </tr>
        </thead>
      @endif
    @endforeach

    @foreach($labelgroup->all() as $label)
      <tbody>
        <tr class="{{ $groep->groep }}">
          <td>{{ $label->label }}</td>
          @if($event->present()->nl)
            <td>{!!  Form::textarea('taal_1',$label->taal_1, array('id' => $label->id.'_1','rows' => 2, 'data-taal' => 'taal_1', 'data-url' => LinkHelper::route('label.update',$label->id),'class' => 'form-control', 'onchange' => 'initialise.update("'.LinkHelper::route('label.update',$label->id).'","taal_1",this.value);')) !!}</td>
          @endif
          @if($event->present()->fr)
            <td>{!!  Form::textarea('taal_2',$label->taal_2, array('id' => $label->id.'_2','rows' => 2, 'data-taal' => 'taal_2', 'data-url' => LinkHelper::route('label.update',$label->id),'class' => 'form-control', 'onchange' => 'initialise.update("'.LinkHelper::route('label.update',$label->id).'","taal_2",this.value);')) !!}</td>
          @endif
          @if($event->present()->en)
            <td>{!!  Form::textarea('taal_3',$label->taal_3, array('id' => $label->id.'_3','rows' => 2, 'data-taal' => 'taal_3','data-url' => LinkHelper::route('label.update',$label->id),'class' => 'form-control', 'onchange' => 'initialise.update("'.LinkHelper::route('label.update',$label->id).'","taal_3",this.value);')) !!}</td>
          @endif
          @if($event->present()->de)
            <td>{!!  Form::textarea('taal_4',$label->taal_4, array('id' => $label->id.'_4','rows' => 2, 'data-taal' => 'taal_4','data-url' => LinkHelper::route('label.update',$label->id),'class' => 'form-control', 'onchange' => 'initialise.update("'.LinkHelper::route('label.update',$label->id).'","taal_4",this.value);')) !!}</td>
          @endif
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    @endforeach
  @endforeach
</table>
```

The table code generates the following table; the image is a part of the table:

[image: Table example]

Because the columns and rows are dynamically inserted I have no idea how to do a click event in which I can say that when I click on the header `<th>` element, I can hide the underlaying `<td>` elements (which represent labels that belong to the `<th>` group). Every `<th>` can have a different amount of rows corresponding with that 'group'.

Could somebody give me some indicators as to how I'm supposed to do this?

Comment: Just add <tr class="HiddenRows"> and in CSS .HiddenRows{display: none} and in javascript you can remove this class.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to approach the rows below a header because I define the rows somewhere else and can't get to them through DOM as far as I can tell.

Comment: Is there any user interaction on those rows? if yes then you can or there should be something to identify the rows to hide. you want to hide all rows or specific rows?

Comment: There will be user interaction later on, here's the basic idea:
We get the groups and labels from the database and place them in the table like in the picture, then I want to be able to click on the green tableheader elements to show or hide the labels because there are a lot of labels on the page. When you open up the table header the corresponding rows should be displayed and later there will be an edit and save button added to each row as well to change the textarea content.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.class').on('click',function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('hiddenRow');
})
```

This will apply a click event on any elements with the class `.class` and when you click on it, it will toggle the class `hiddenRow`

Comment: I can not work with classes like this because I don't want to close ALL tr tags. The reason this does not work is because I add elements to the table with a loop ->  @foreach($labelgroup as $groep) and therefor can't seem to find a way to give these elements a unique class which I can use to do event handling with.

Comment: You don't need a unique class for each TR. You use one class for all TR's to hide them, and then when you click on a row with that class you remove the class from the row, there by showing only the row you are clicking on, you can run through a loop and add the class back if you want to hide it again